# beancreation exception throws when use two foreign keys from the same table

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, foreign-key-relationship

I use mssql server and hibernate3 in my project.i am getting the below exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.uniphore.timesheet.domain.TblBaseLine.tblUserDetails in com.uniphore.timesheet.domain.TblUserDetails.tblBaseLinesForApproverId
```

i use two foriegn key from  the same table.But i don't know how to write annotation for this.

For example consider the below model

```
User    
userid(PK)
role 
name

Assignment
AssignmentID(pk)
studentID(Fk_User)
professiorID(Fk_user)
```

Below Is My Classes:
TblBaseline

```
package com.uniphore.timesheet.domain;



import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="tblBaseLine")
public class TblBaseLine  implements java.io.Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1798070786993154671L;
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     @Column(name ="ID")
     private int id;
     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="ModifierID")
     private TblUserDetails tblUserDetailsByModifierId;
     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="ApproverID")
     private TblUserDetails tblUserDetailsByApproverId;

     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tblBaseLine", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private Set<TblPhaseBaseLine> tblPhaseBaseLines = new HashSet<TblPhaseBaseLine>(0);

    public TblBaseLine() {
    }


    public TblBaseLine(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


}
```

TblPhaseBaseLine

```
package com.uniphore.timesheet.domain;



import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="tblPhaseBaseLine")
public class TblPhaseBaseLine  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1798070786993154674L;
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     @Column(name ="ID")
     private int id;
     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name ="PhaseID")
     private TblProjectPhase tblProjectPhase;
     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name ="BaseLineID")
     private TblBaseLine tblBaseLine;

     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tblPhaseBaseLine", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private Set<TblProjectPhase> tblProjectPhases = new HashSet<TblProjectPhase>(0);

    public TblPhaseBaseLine() {
    }


    public TblPhaseBaseLine(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }




}
```

TblUserDetails:

```
package com.uniphore.timesheet.domain;



import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="tblUserDetails")
public class TblUserDetails  implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1798070786993154686L;
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     @Column(name ="ID")
     private int id;
     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name ="RoleID")
     private TblRoles tblRoles;


     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tblUserDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private Set<TblUserPrevilege> tblUserPrevileges = new HashSet<TblUserPrevilege>(0);
     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tblUserDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private Set<TblProjectApprover> tblProjectApprovers = new HashSet<TblProjectApprover>(0);
     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tblUserDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private Set<TblProjectResource> tblProjectResources = new HashSet<TblProjectResource>(0);
     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tblUserDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private Set<TblTimesheet> tblTimesheetsForApprover = new HashSet<TblTimesheet>(0);
     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tblUserDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private Set<TblBaseLine> tblBaseLinesForModifierId = new HashSet<TblBaseLine>(0);
     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tblUserDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private Set<TblTimesheet> tblTimesheetsForUserId = new HashSet<TblTimesheet>(0);
     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tblUserDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private Set<TblBaseLine> tblBaseLinesForApproverId = new HashSet<TblBaseLine>(0);

    public TblUserDetails() {
    }




}
```

How to avoid this exception?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Too much code to go through!!!

Comment: @Rahul,Okay,I will reduce the unnecessary codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't avoid the exception - you fix the problem. The error is clearly telling you that com.uniphore.timesheet.domain.TblBaseLine does not have an entity property 'tblUserDetails'. And indeed, it doesn't.

So that 'mappedBy' you have on your TblUserDetails is simply wrong, use the proper matching class property name. tblUserDetailsByModifierId or tblUserDetailsByApproverId are the possible property names you can use in the 'mappedBy'.